# Webservice root element is missing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i'm trying to call a webservice from a stored procedure in vs management studio 2012.
this is the webservice i'm trying to invoke

```
 http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?op=GetWeather
```

here you got my stored procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE CallWeatherService
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 @Country varchar(20) = null,
 @City varchar(20) = null
AS

BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
DECLARE @obj INT
DECLARE @response varchar(8000)
DECLARE @serviceUrl VARCHAR(200)



SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET @serviceUrl = 'http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?CityName?Param1=' + @City + '&CountryName?Param2=' + @Country + '' 

EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @obj OUT
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'Open', NULL, 'POST', @serviceUrl, false
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'send'
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'responseText', @response OUT


-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT @response [response]
EXEC sp_OADestroy @obj
END
GO
```

I call my stored procedure:

```
USE [testdatabase]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[CallWeatherService]
    @Country = N'Belgium',
    @City = N'Koksijde'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

However i get the error

```
 System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?